# Magento 2. Add custom button on product grid using the layout handle

Tags: magento2, product, grid

In Magento 1 one could add a custom button on the product grid using the layout handle.

One would add the following to local.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <!-- ... -->
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_index>
        <reference name="products_list">
            <action method="addButton">
                <id>my_button_identifier</id>
                <data>
                    <label>My button</label>
                    <class>some-class</class>
                    <onclick>some_click_action_here</onclick>
                </data>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_index>
    <!-- ... -->
</layout>
```

- Is this possible in Magento 2? If so how?

I've tried with no luck:

**Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="products_list">
            <action method="addButton">
                <argument name="buttonId" xsi:type="string">button_id</argument>
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Button Label</item>
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">frontname/controller/controller</item>
                    <item name="class_name" xsi:type="string">Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button</item> <!-- Tried without this node as well -->
                </argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

EDIT

I can confirm that the addButton Method is called for my input, yet the button still is not displayed in frontend

Comment: Can You Please Provide Some More Information> @vitoriodachef

Comment: More information regarding what?

Answer (score 1):

On Magento 2, you can add custom button in product listing by this creating file: app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="priority_import_products_all">
                <url path="priority/sync/products"/>
                <label translate="true">Your button title</label>
                <class>action-secondary</class>
            </button>
        </buttons>
    </settings>
</listing>
```

Result:
[image]