# Create custom button on catalog > product page in admin panel

Tags: magento2

How can i create button on Product listing page in admin menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The product form is generated via ui-components.
The ui component name for product form is view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml.

You need to create a file with the same name and path in your own module with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="button-unique-identifier-here" xsi:type="string">[Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\CustomButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</form>
```

Then create the class

> [Namespace][Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\CustomButton.php
>    in this file write below code

```
<?php 
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Generic;

class CustomButton extends Generic
{
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Your button label here'),
            'on_click' => "alert('it works')",
            'sort_order' => 100
        ];
    }
}
```

Your Button will display in your product form.

Comment: Not working for Magento 2.2

Comment: I want to open a form by clicking on this button is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

you can follow following links to create the custom button...

[Magento 2. Add custom button on product grid using the layout handle](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229843/magento-2-add-custom-button-on-product-grid-using-the-layout-handle)

or you can create one file under [vendor]/[module]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="priority_import_products_all">
                <url path="priority/sync/products"/>
                <label translate="true">Custom Button Name</label>
                <class>action-secondary</class>
            </button>
        </buttons>
    </settings>
</listing>
```

[image]